# I have an SQL query which links 3 tables using UNION:

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql ="(SELECT Drive.DriveID,Ram.Memory from Drive,Ram where Drive.DriveID = Ram.RamID) UNION
(SELECT Drive.DriveID,External.Memory from Drive, External where Drive.DriveID = External.ExtID)";
```

Suppose I want to get Ram.Name as well. How do I do this? If I use Ram.Name in the first SELECT statement it would not produce the correct result.

Any method for tackling this? I want to do it using UNION.

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
SELECT Drive.DriveID,Ram.Memory,Ram.Name 
FROM Drive,Ram WHERE Drive.DriveID = Ram.RamID
UNION
SELECT Drive.DriveID,External.Memory,NULL 
FROM Drive, External WHERE Drive.DriveID = External.ExtID
```

this will have NULL in the fourth column for all of the results of the second select

Comment: 4th column should not be displayed ,evenas an empty column

Comment: @work: You can't do a UNION of a two column query and a three column query so either you do two queries or you add a bit of code to filter out the NULL.